Want to add nested data into MongoDB, I am working in Djongo, I have tried both the foreign key and EmbededField but unable to get nested data into DB
I am working in Django, I have tried both the foreign key and EmbedField but unable to get nested data into MongoDB, when run migrations
I created two models in MongoDB, my models are:
class Employee(models.Model):
    id=models.ObjectIdField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    email=models.EmailField()
    phone_number=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
       return self.name
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email=models.EmailField()
    employees = models.ArrayField(
        model_container=Employee,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    
    def __str__(self):
      return self.name

and the data I am getting in Company collection is like:
 {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "66c8b0c7fc77e7422da0e80d"
  },
  "id": 2,
  "name": "dgdhg",
  "description": "abhdj",
  "location": "sdsgh",
  "email": "xeno@gmail.com"
}

But i want to show data like this
{
        "name": "John",
        "location": "Sargodha",
        "description": "kjjlyyf",
        "email": "hvh@gmail.com",
        "employees": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "hassan",
                "age": 23,
                "email": "adeebhassi@gmail.com",
                "company": 1,
                "phone_number": "2394820948"
            }
        ]
    },


It looks like the code didn't format correctly, and I'm not clear what the title is asking. Can you please edit the question to fix the formatting and change the title to be more clear?

I apologize for my mistake. Would you kindly check it now?

This isn’t Django but Djongo. [Edit] your tags to properly represent your question because as it is, your question is completely misrepresented.

@ChukwujiobiCanon Yeah you are right it Djongo , not Django, i think now question look ok to show the issue , Please suggest me solution for this

It seems that no value was entered for the ArrayField using the ORM hence it was completely left out. If this is not the case, share the ORM command you are using to enter a value.

Simply sending the data from postman
 "name": "John Doe",
 "email": "john.doe@example.com",
 "age": 35,
 "addresses": [
   {
     "street": "123 Main St",
     "city": "Anytown",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip_code": "12345"
   }
 ]
}" ```
